# Symfony2 collection field for simple list of emails to be sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to accomplish a very basic task: I'd like to have a form with one field (an email address), and an "add" button so that you can add other email addresses. I'll later send emails to each of the addresses passed.

I came across [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), which in theory is exactly what I need. I'm fine creating the form inside the controller directly, as I'll use it only here. Here is the function inside the controller:

```
public function createHRAction(Request $request)
{


$data = array();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
// each item in the array will be an "email" field
'type'   => 'email',
// these options are passed to each "email" type
'options'  => array(
    'required'  => false,
    'attr'      => array('class' => 'email-box'),
    'prototype' => true,
    'allow_add' => true,
    ),
))->getForm();


$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
    {
    //$form->bind($request);

    // $data is a simply array with your form fields 
    $data = $form->getData();
    return $this->render('HR/invitationSent.html.twig', array('data' => $data,));
    }
return $this->render('HR/createForm.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```

And here is the twig:

> ```
> {% extends "internal.html.twig" %}
>
> {% block content %}
> {{ form_start(form) }}
>     {# 
>
>     {# store the prototype on the data-prototype attribute #}
>     <ul id="email-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.emails.vars.prototype)|e }}">
>     {% for emailField in form.emails %}
>         <li>
>             {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
>             {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
>         </li>
>     {% endfor %}
>     </ul>
>
>     <a href="#" id="add-another-email">Add another email</a>
>
>      #}
> {{ form_end(form) }}
>
> {% endblock content %}
>
> {% block javascripts %}
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
>     // keep track of how many email fields have been rendered
>     var emailCount = '{{ form.emails|length }}';
>
>     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>         jQuery('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
>             e.preventDefault();
>
>             var emailList = jQuery('#email-fields-list');
>
>             // grab the prototype template
>             var newWidget = emailList.attr('data-prototype');
>             // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
>             // with a number that's unique to your emails
>             // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
>             newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, emailCount);
>             emailCount++;
>
>             // create a new list element and add it to the list
>             var newLi = jQuery('<li></li>').html(newWidget);
>             newLi.appendTo(emailList);
>         });
>     })
> </script>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

I get the following error:

> Key "prototype" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name,
>   full_name, disabled, label, label_format, multipart, block_prefixes,
>   unique_block_prefix, translation_domain, cache_key, read_only, errors,
>   valid, data, required, max_length, pattern, size, label_attr,
>   compound, method, action, submitted, allow_add, allow_delete" does not
>   exist in HR/createForm.html.twig at line 8

I thought I solved it by adding the lines:

> ```
>     'prototype' => true,
>     'allow_add' => true,
> ```

but in effect it did not change anything :(

Tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'prototype' and 'allow_add' are their own options.  The 'options' is the array passed to the form type you specify in 'type' (so what each 'email' option would have, in this case).  See the documentation here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Your form creation should look like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
        'type'      => 'email',
        'prototype' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'options'   => array(
            'required'  => false,
            'attr'      => array('class' => 'email-box'),
        )
    )
)->getForm();
```

Comment: Thank you, it apparently worked. I mean apparently because at least it does not give me any errors. The bad news is that when I click the button nothing happens. I've put an alert inside the script, and I discovered that I never reach the javascript code :(

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the last little bug, I had to move the src="..." inside the head. Thanks a lot for your help!!! I'd like to upvote but I don't have the necessary privilege. As soon I do I will!

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped.  You should be able to set mine as the Accepted Answer until you have upvote privileges.